# SQL query - joins + counting

Tags: sql, join, count, oracle11g

Here's my problem: I have a query that joins multiple tables to show details of some orders. The query result in a table with columns:

```
order ID | name | count | price | location | date
```

It's a hospital database and what i want to do is to add another column that says how many patients were at that location at given date.

There's another table that shows patient stays - I need to count those.

```
patient ID | location | dateFrom | dateTo
```

The thing is that the `STAYS` table shows 2 dates - FROM and TO so I need to count every patient that was present at given location (ward) when order was placed.

Here's the initial query I need to update:

```
SELECT 
    AP_ZAMPOZ.ID_TOW AS IDTowaru, --merchandiseID
    GMSL_TOW.NAZWA_TOW AS Nazwa, --name
    GMSL_TOW.MNOZNIK_SYN AS Mnoznik, --quantity
    AP_ZAMPOZ.ZAM_CENA_S AS Cena, --price
    AP_ZAMPOZ.ZAM_IL AS Ilosc, --count
    AP_ZAMNAG.ZAM_DATE AS DataZam, --date
    GMSL_MAG.NAZWA_MAG AS Magazyn, --location
    APSL_TOW_PROD.PROD_NAZWA AS Producent, --producer
    APSL_TOW_ATC.NAZWA AS Grupa -group
FROM 
    AP_ZAMPOZ
JOIN 
    GMSL_TOW ON AP_ZAMPOZ.ID_TOW = GMSL_TOW.ID_TOW 
JOIN 
    AP_ZAMNAG ON AP_ZAMNAG.ZAM_ID_NAG = AP_ZAMPOZ.ZAM_ID_NAG
JOIN 
    GMSL_MAG ON AP_ZAMNAG.ID_MAG = GMSL_MAG.ID_MAG
JOIN 
    APSL_TOW ON AP_ZAMPOZ.ID_TOW = APSL_TOW.ID_TOW
LEFT JOIN 
    APSL_TOW_PROD ON APSL_TOW.ID_PROD = APSL_TOW_PROD.ID_PROD
LEFT JOIN 
    APSL_TOW_ATC ON APSL_TOW.KOD = APSL_TOW_ATC.KOD
```

The table with `stays` is called `POBYT` and has these relevant columns:

```
| ID_POB (ID) | IDK_JOS (location identifier) | DT_OD (date From) | DT_TO (date To)
```

Rows that I would like to see should look like those in my present query + number of patients at given location at given date.

Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this? I'm stuck...

Comment: It's a **QUERY** - one "r" is quite enough ! And also: for which concrete database is this? SQL is the query language used by many databases, but knowing which concrete database (and which version!) you're using could be helpful to someone trying to be of assistance.

Comment: sry - english isnt my mother language.
the database is Oracle 11g

Comment: And depending on your RDBMS (db flavor), there are a number of examples of this kind of query on the site.  This is a variation on gaps-and-islands.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by adding subquery as another SELECT column. 
Heres the code

```
SELECT

.
.
.
 APSL_TOW_ATC.NAZWA AS Grupa

(SELECT Count(*)
FROM pobyt 
WHERE (TO_DATE( AP_ZAMNAG.ZAM_DATE, 'YY/MM/DD')  >= TO_DATE(DT_OD, 'YY-MM-DD') AND (TO_DATE( AP_ZAMNAG.ZAM_DATE, 'YY/MM/DD')  <= TO_DATE(DT_DO, 'YY-MM-DD') OR dt_do IS NULL))
AND IDK_JOS = GMSL_MAG.KOD_MAG) AS LiczbaPacjentow --no. of patients at given date

FROM AP_ZAMPOZ
.
.
.
```

Works great.